# How would I pronounce the symbol $[E:F]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, galois-theory, extension-field, pronunciation

Recently I have been reading algebraic extension by own and get the symbol $[E:F]$. My question is how would I pronounce this symbol?

Comment: "The degree of the extension $E$ over $F$" or something like that

Answer (score 3):

It should be read "the degree of $E$ over $F$."

(And good on you for asking. For some reason, in my head, I always say "$E$ chop $F$."  Sometimes this slips out in mathematical conversations and people have no idea what I'm talking about.  Don't develop my habits.)